# PC does not automatically switch back when Headphones are plugged out of Front Panel audio jack

Tags: audio, headset, front-panel

I have a Xonar DS sound card and a BitFenix Shinobi Case. When I plug in my Headphones into the front panel audio jack the speakes automatically mute and I can hear sound from the headphones, but when I plug them out it does not automatically switch back. I have to go to the Xonar DS Audio center and switch back manually.

This should be a Windows problem since it works flawlessly when I boot into Ubuntu, but I can not find where I can configure this.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This sounds like a driver problem.  You didn't mention what version of Windows.  I would contact Xonar with regard to this issue.

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit =/

Comment: Have you contacted Xonar with regards to this problem?

Comment: I have contacted Asus about this, lets see what they come up with ^^

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me a time ago, what happened to me was that the setting for the speakers was disabled, you can fix something like this by entering in the audio properties of windows audio, and enabling the speakers again and set them as the default "audio output".

Comment: no this is not it, the speakers are default all the time. Somehow in Windows the driver or whatever does not notice when I unplug the headphones

Comment: the other option is that the Driver is not installed correctly download it from the support page of you PC or look for the best option of driver for it. hope it helps :)